# How the y is returning 1 without passing anything to it?

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone explain to me how the y is returning 1 in this code?

```
def f(x):
    def g(y):
        print(y)
        return y + x + 3 
    return g

nf1 = f(1)

print(nf1(1))
```

Result:

```
1

5
```

Comment: That only outputs `5`.

Comment: I edited the code @jonrsharpe,please check it now

Comment: That's **not** the output of the code you've shown, which is different to what's in the screenshot (but screenshots of code aren't useful). What you've shown only outputs `5`. Also you *do* pass something to `y`, when you call `nf1` (which is what the generated `g` gets assigned to).

Comment: I didn't pass anything to 'g' , I don't understand why 'y' is always 1.

Comment: It's *not* always 1. It's whatever you pass when you call nf1 (which *is* g, which you *do* pass something to).

Comment: @MiladSaeedi - think I wasn't very accurate there; `f(x)` returns `g` and defines `x` for `g` since it is in its outer scope. When you then call `f(x)(y)`, both `x` and `y` are defined. To avoid confusion, use nested functions with care ;-) ...especially when it comes to using variables from the outer scope inside functions. that can make for some pretty unreadable, hard-to-debug code.

Comment: @MrFuppes noted thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically calling `print(f(1)(1))` in the last line. Hence both x and y are 1. Function `g` returns 5 and the print inside `g` prints `y` which is 1.

Comment: so as you said if I `print(nf1(1)(3))` , `y` should print 3 but I got this error:`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: If you look at my answer... I said `f(1)(1)` not `nf1(1)(1)`!